# Vue/TypeScript Instance member is not accessible

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webstorm

I'm going to preface this question by stating that I'm unsure if this issue is related to Vue, TypeScript, or possibly the mix of the two.

In my project, I'm using Adonis.js as my backend with Vue3 for the frontend. I have created a declarations file (`index.d.ts`) that holds interfaces for the models I use in my backend, so I have a way of using type hinting in the frontend.

A snippet of my declaration file:

```
declare module 'Models' {
    interface BaseModel {
        id: number
        createdAt: Date
        updatedAt: Date
    }

    export interface Galaxy extends BaseModel {
        name: string
        systems: System[]
    }

    // ... and so on
}
```

When I import and use these interfaces as types within normal TypeScript files or within a `<script setup lang="ts">` element, it all behaves as expected. However within the `<script setup>` blocks, I have defined a computed property with the type of `ComputedRef<Galaxy|null>` and when I use this computed property within the Vue template, my IDE provides a warning:

> Instance member is not accessible
> `module:Models.Galaxy.name: string`

So far I've basically just ignored these because everything works fine, however I was hoping there was a way to fix this as it can be distracting. Is this an issue with Vue3 or TypeScript? Perhaps my IDE (WebStorm 2021.3.1)?

Comment: Please, specify your code instead of describing it. Did you try to use `<script>` instead of `<script setup>`? Does the error occur at build time? If it's not then the problem is specific to IDE and likely needs to be solved from their side.

Comment: @EstusFlask Switching from `<script setup>` to `<script>` would completely change my code. Also, as stated, it works fine in the script block. As stated, my IDE provides a warning, there is no error. When TypeScript is involved however, my IDE can provide lots of warnings, but there's normally a way (in code) to make the warning go away.

Comment: You didn't provide the code. It's unknown if you imported `Models`. If it doesn't occur anywhere but IDE then I'd suggest to solve it with IDE support. Such TS problems are often tool-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn off `Unresolved TypeScript reference` in IDE settings

[image: WebStorm Example]